# LaTeX/BibTeX: Citations beginning with ``W'' not showing up

Tags: bibtex, natbib

When I compile my document, all of my citations where the label begins with a W are not showing up and I'm getting an error when I compile in LaTeX that each citation is "undefined". The my .bib runs perfectly without errors and when I add other new entries, it works just fine, so I'm confused. I don't think it has to do with the W per se, but clearly something is happening where my the whole .bib isn't being read when I compile. Any tips to troubleshoot this would be great..

Example of the Errors in LaTeX:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Woods_2017' on page 14 undefined on input line 162.
[14] [15] [16]
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Census_2020' on page 17 undefined on input line 184.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Weller_Hanks_2018' on page 17 undefined on input line 184.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wang_2018' on page 17 undefined on input line 190.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wang_2018' on page 17 undefined on input line 190.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wang_2018' on page 17 undefined on input line 190.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wilderson_2017' on page 17 undefined on input line 190.
```

Comment: Can you open the `.bbl` file and check if the relevant "W" references are present there? Double check that your `.bib` file contains these references as well. Just to be sure, look at the `.blg` file and check not only for errors but also for warnings or other interesting messages.

Comment: What are the entry types of `Woods_2017`, `Census_2020`, `Weller_Hanks_2018`, `Wang_2018`, and `Wilderson_2017`?

Comment: thanks for these comments... all the entries are in the .bbl file, they are all either books or articles

Comment: If the entries are present in the `.bbl` they must be found after to subsequent LaTeX runs. If that is not the case, something is seriously wrong. Unfortunately, we can't investigate what might be wrong with the information provided so far. I realise that it is a lot to ask, but would it be possible to create a short example document that reproduces the issue (an MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). We need to know more about your setup to be even able to begin to guess what might be wrong

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was apparently caused by an unescaped ampersand in the `.bib` file (see the now deleted self-answer). This error is not apparent from the error messages shared so far. There was also no code shared that would help with the investigation. Voting to close since in its current form the question is unlikely to help future visitors and the issue is resolved.